# Download any filetype from a webserver

Tags: javascript, html, download

I need a link in an HTML page that could use any JavaScript to "start downloading" a normal webpage / file that is on my webserver, either filetypes like PDF / ZIP or simply the outputs of PHP / ASP / HTML.

I know this is possible with some server-side download script that returns a *mime_content_type* so the browser handles it based on its configuration. (typically Download) but I would really like a JavaScript-only solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to force a download dialog, no matter what the file type is (i.e., don't open PDF's in the browser using Adobe Reader, or render HTML pages, etc.)? If that's the case, you can add the header "Content-Disposition: attachment;" on the server-side. I don't know of a way to force this on the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to force the browser to display the Save As dialog I uses the following headers:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test.pdf
```

Comment: Hate to downvote, but this is ignoring the question. He asked for a javascript-only solution. To change the response headers, you need something server side.

Answer (score 3):

You simply cannot do that in javascript, as you need to change the mime type header. The best you could do is to use open('the url') to open it in another window, but I don't think that fits to your needs and could be blocked by popup blockers.

Comment: If you target only IE users, you could use a method like this, but I would not recommend it !

Answer (score 1):

That has to be done server-side. To do it on an Apache Server, add this to your `.htaccess` file: `AddType application/octet-stream mp3` where mp3 is the filetype that needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to serve the file using the webserver as Fabien points out. For example with ASP you would give the file a content type before serving the file:

```
Response.contenttype = "application/octet-stream"
```